# Finding $n$ points on a cube such that the distance between them is maximized.

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

Suppose a unit cube. How can I place $n$ points on it (or in it, although I suspect that that will only be optimal for a large $n$) such that the sum of the distances between all pairs of points is maximized?

For $n=2$ this is trivially the opposite vertices. For $n=8$ it seems like it is obviously all vertices. But how do I find this for general $n$?

Comment: I suspect this problem has no easy  solution. It's hard for the sphere, which is much more symmetrical. If you [edit] the question to tell us why you need the answer (other than just plain curiosity) we may be able to help.

Comment: Have you tried using optimizers to find answers for various cases of $n$? There might be some nice patterns.

Comment: In the optimal configuration of points in cube which maximizes the sum of pairwise distance, all the points lie on the 8 vertices. This can be proved using following property of distance function:
Take any two distinct points $p, q \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and perturb $p$ for a small distance $t$ along direction $v$. As a function of $t$, $|(p+vt) - q|$ is a convex. Furthermore, it is strictly convex unless $v \parallel p - q$.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

1. For any optimal configuration of placing $n$ points in cube to maximize the sum of pairwise distances, all the points lie on the 8 vertices.
2. For $n = 8m + k$ where $0 \le k < 8$, an optimal configuration can be constructed as follows:

   - place $k$ points on the $8$ vertices according to configuration $V_k$ illustrated below.
   - place $m$ extra points on each of the 8 vertices.

[image: The 8 basic configurations V_k]

**The boring details**

Before we start, let use recall some thing in calculus.

> For any $a \ne 0$, consider the function $f(t) = \sqrt{t^2+a^2}$. Since $f''(t) = \frac{a^2}{(t^2+a^2)^{\frac32}} > 0$, $f(t)$ is strictly convex in $t$. if we set $a$ to $0$, $f(t)$ becomes $|t|$ which isn't strictly convex but still remains to be a convex function.

Using this, we can deduce:

> Given any two point $p, q \in \mathbb{R}^d$. If one perturb $p$ along direction $v$ for a small distance $t$, the distance $|(p+vt)-q|$ is always a convex function in $t$. If $p \ne q$ and $v \not\parallel p - q$, it will be strictly convex in $t$.

Take any convex polytope $K$ (closed, bounded, with non-empty interior) in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Consider the problem of picking $n$ points $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ from $K$ and maximizing the sum of pairwise distance:

$$\mathcal{S}(p_1,\ldots,p_n) \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{1\le i < j \le n} |p_i - p_j| = \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|p_i-p_j|$$

This sum is a continuous function over $K^n$. Since $K$ is closed/bounded and hence compact, $K^n$ is also compact. This implies the maximum of $\mathcal{S}(\dots)$ will be attained by some configuration $(p'_1,\ldots, p'_n)$ in $K^n$.

It is trivial to see the points $p'_k$ don't lie on a single line. If any point in this set, say $p'_\ell$, isn't an extremal point of $K$, then there is a direction $v$ and a $\epsilon > 0$ so that $p'_\ell + v t \in K$ whenever $|t| \le \epsilon$.
The perturbed sum of distances
$$S_{\ell,v}(t) \stackrel{def}{=} S(p'_1,\ldots,p'_{\ell-1},p'_\ell + vt,p'_{\ell+1},\ldots,p'_n)$$
is the sum of a bunch of convex functions in $t$. Since the points $p'_k$ don't lie on a single line, some of these functions are strictly convex. This means
$S_{\ell,v}(t)$ is strictly convex in $t$. As a result, at least one of
$S_{\ell,v}(\pm \epsilon) > S_{\ell,v}(0)$. Since $p'_\ell \pm v\epsilon \in K$.
This contradicts with the optimality of the configuration $(p'_1,\ldots,p'_n)$.

From these, we can conclude:

> In any configuration that maximize the sum of pairwise distances of $n$ points in $K$, all the points lie on extremal points of $K$.

In particular, for the problem at hand where $d = 3$ and $K = [0,1]^3$, all the points in the optimal configuration $\in \{0,1\}^3$, the $8$ vertices of the cube.

Label the $8$ vertices as $e_0,\ldots,e_7$ where $e_{i+2j+4k} = (i,j,k)$ for $(i,j,k) \in \{0,1\}^3$.

Let $N$ be the $8\times 1$ column vector whose $\ell$-th entry, $n_\ell$, is  number of points we place on $e_\ell$.

Let $U_0$ be the $8 \times 1$ column vector with all entries $1$ and $M$ be the $8 \times 8$ matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & \sqrt{2} & 1 & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{3}\\
1 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 1 & \sqrt{2} & 1 & \sqrt{3} & \sqrt{2}\\
1 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 1 & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{3} & 1 & \sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{2} & 1 & 1 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & 1\\
1 & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 1 & 1 & \sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{2} & 1 & \sqrt{3} & \sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 1\\
\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{3} & 1 & \sqrt{2} & 1 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 1\\
\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & 1 & \sqrt{2} & 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

In terms of $M,N$, the sum of distance can be rewritten as
$$\mathcal{S}(p_1,\ldots,p_n) = \frac12 N^T M N$$

The problem becomes maximize this expression subjective to
$N \in \mathbb{N}^8$ (ie. all entries of $N$ is non-negative integers) and $U_0^T N = n$.

To proceed further, we need more properties about $M$. Introduce $7$ more column vectors $U_1,\ldots,U_7$:

$$\begin{array}{llrrrrrrr}
U_1^T &= [1, &-1, & 1, &-1, & 1, &-1, & 1, &-1],\\
U_2^T &= [1, & 1, &-1, &-1, & 1, & 1, &-1, &-1],\\
U_3^T &= [1, &-1, &-1, & 1, & 1, &-1, &-1, & 1],\\
U_4^T &= [1, & 1, & 1, & 1, &-1, &-1, &-1, &-1],\\
U_5^T &= [1, &-1, & 1, &-1, &-1, & 1, &-1, & 1],\\
U_6^T &= [1, & 1, &-1, &-1, &-1, &-1, & 1, & 1],\\
U_7^T &= [1, &-1, &-1, & 1, &-1, & 1, & 1, &-1]\,
\end{array}$$
Together with $U_0$, they form a spanning set of eigenvectors of $M$ with eigenvalues:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
U_0 & : & \lambda_0 = 3\sqrt{2} + (\sqrt{3}+3) \sim 8.97469\\
U_7 & : & \lambda_1 = 3\sqrt{2} - (\sqrt{3}+3) \sim -0.48941\\
U_3,U_5,U_6 & : &\lambda_2 = -\sqrt{2} + (\sqrt{3}-1) \sim -0.68216\\
U_1,U_2,U_4 & : & \lambda_3 = -\sqrt{2} - (\sqrt{3}-1) \sim -2.14626
\end{array}$$
The key is aside from $\lambda_0$, the other three eigenvalues are negative and $\le\lambda_1$.

For $k = 0, \ldots, 7$, let $V_k$ be the column vectors defined by:
$$\begin{align} 
V_0^T &= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],\\
V_1^T &= [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],\\
V_2^T &= [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],\\
V_3^T &= [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0],\\
V_4^T &= [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0],\\
V_5^T &= [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],\\
V_6^T &= [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],\\
V_7^T &= [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
\end{align}$$
For $n = 8m+k \ge 8$, let $V_n = V_k + mU_0$. We claim that:

> Among all configurations of placing $n$ points on 8 vertices of the cube, $V_n$ is one which maximizes the sum of pairwise distances.

Mathematically, this is equivalent to the statement:

$$V^T_n M V_n \ge N^T M N\quad \forall N \in \mathbb{N}^8, U^T_0\cdot N = n$$

Assume for some $n$, there is a $N$ which violate this. What does such a $N$ need to satisfy?

Let $\mu = \frac{n}{8}$.
Since $U^T_0 V_n = U^T_0 N = n$, both $V_n -\mu U_0$ and $N - \mu U_0$ is orthogonal to $U_0$.
Together with $U_0$ is an eigenvector of $M$, it is not hard to see

$$\begin{align} & N^T M N > V^T_n M V_n\\
\iff & N^T M N - \mu^2 U^T_0 M U_0 > V^T_n M V_n - \mu^2 U^T_0 M U_0\\
\iff & (N - \mu U_0)^T M (N - \mu U_0) > (V_n - \mu U_0)^T M (V_n - \mu U_0)\\
\implies & \lambda_1 |N-\mu U_0|^2 > (V_n - \mu U_0)^T M (V_n - \mu U_0)\\
\end{align}$$
Notice both $\lambda_1$ and RHS are negative, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^8 |n_k - \mu|^2 = | N-\mu U_0|^2 < \frac{(V_n - \mu U_0)^T M (V_n - \mu U_0)}{\lambda_1}$$

Among all $n$, $\displaystyle\;\frac{(V_n - \mu U_0)^T M (V_n - \mu U_0)}{\lambda_1}\;$ is maximized when $n \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$ with value

$$\frac{9(\sqrt{3}+3)-21\sqrt{2}}{8(3+\sqrt{3}-3\sqrt{2})}\sim 3.292221574424036 < 4$$
This means for any $N$ that does better than $V_n$, all its $n_i$ satsify $|n_i - \mu| < 2$.

To search for an $N$ that outperform $V_n$, we can restrict ourselves to configurations where
$$\lfloor \mu \rfloor - 1 \le n_i \le \lceil \mu \rceil + 1, \quad i = 0,\ldots, 7$$
and there are only $4^8 = 65536$ configurations to check.

I write a script to cover all these configurations and I didn't find anything that does better than $V_n$. In the script, I also keep track of those which perform as good as $V_n$ (up to some numerical rounding error). It turns out all of them can be obtained from $V_n$ by Euclidean isometries. In conclusion:

> For any $n$, the configurations which maximize the sum of pairwise distances of $n$ points in cube are those obtainable from $V_n$ by Euclidean isometries. The number of optimal configurations are
> $$\begin{cases}
> 1, & n \equiv 0 \pmod 8\\
> 2, & n \equiv 4 \pmod 8\\
> 4, & n \equiv 2 \pmod 4\\
> 8, & n \equiv 1 \pmod 2
> \end{cases}$$